# Can we use integration to find $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {4k}{4{k}^{4}+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We can simply use comparison test to know whether this series converges or diverges, obviously this one converges but how do we find the actual value after summation?

Can we use integration? I'm preparing for an exam and they are permitting 3 minutes to max 5 minutes per question, so how can i tackle questions like this that will help me find sum under 5 minutes?

Comment: partial fractions?

Comment: Why do you think the sum converges?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%3D1+to+infinity+%284k%2F%284k%5E4%2B1%29%29 According to WA, the sum is equal to 1.

Comment: Note  $4k^4+1= (2k^2+2k+1)(2k^2-2k+1)$ which  is easily obtained by [Sophia Germaine identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sophie-germain-identity/#:~:text=She%20discovered%20this%20identity%20in,is%20common%20in%20contest%20mathematics.) and rest is telescoping sum. He same  problem is [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/sophie-germain-and-series/).

Comment: @Naren that was really useful, thank you so much for showing the expansion!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\frac{4k}{4k^{4}+1}=\frac{4k}{(4k^{4}+4k^{2}+1)-4k^{2}}=\frac{4k}{(2k^{2}+2k+1)(2k^{k}-2k+1)}=\frac{1}{2k^{2}-2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k^{2}+2k+1}$ and thus $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{4k}{4k^{4}+1}=1-\frac{1}{2n^{2}+2n+1}$, so finally $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4k}{4k^{4}+1}=1$.

Comment: I'm so so sorry, i just have 1 doubt, how did you make 1/(2$k^2$-2k+1) into 1?

Comment: When you take a finite sum you'll see that all terms except the first and last term  cancel, try it!

Comment: +1. You have a "good eye". Nice answer.

Comment: +1. Is there a way to see that the latter sum is telescopic apart from summing some of the initial terms?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any faster way, but it's easy to see from the first few terms. Maybe see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104918/how-to-analyze-convergence-and-sum-of-a-telescopic-series-i-cant-find-a-generi and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series.